# How do I get text from input text box in selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation, jestjs

I need to insert with selenium to text box and then get it to another use.

[image]

how can I do this? 
The function `getText()` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to get the data from attribute value.

driver.findElement(By.id("text-box")).getAttribute("value");

If the above does not work then I believe the JavascriptExecutor will definitely help you to achieve the same.